# Adding numbers to sub-lists?

Tags: org-mode

So when you have a numbered list in Org Mode, it looks like this:

[image]

But I want my numbered lists to look like this:

[image]

With the sub-sections having the parent section's number as well. Is there any way I can do this? Any extension or anything like that?